# Ajuda com criação de curva ABC em Mysql

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Montei um select para saber qtos produtos forma vendidos em determinado período e o valor de venda desses produtos.

Só que preciso montar uma curva ABC com o resultado desse select.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor.

Meu select está assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.cat_id prod, p.id, p.nome id_prod, SUM( d.qtd ) AS qtd_prod, SUM( d.valor_total ) AS total_prod
FROM lc_controle c
INNER JOIN lc_detalhe d ON d.controle_id = c.id
INNER JOIN  `lc_cat` p ON p.id = d.cat_id
WHERE d.tipo =  '0'
AND c.dtConcat
BETWEEN  '2018-01-01'
AND  '2018-03-31'
GROUP BY d.cat_id
ORDER BY qtd_prod DESC
```

Com esse select eu tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
prod    id  id_prod qtd_prod    total_prod
43  43  JVP-101A - BOMBA DE CIRCULAÇÃO 3.000 L/H 110V   353 12983.24
41  41  JVP-100A - BOMBA DE CIRCULAÇÃO 2.500 L/H 110V   352 10704.09
148 148 JVP-110A - BOMBA DE CIRCULAÇÃO 2.000 L/H 110V   242 7495.04
78  78  HJS-20 CARVÃO ATIVADO 500GR     208 1497.87
252 252 JVP-120 - BOMBA DE CIRCULAÇÃO 3.000 L/H 110V    181 5753.87
```

Agora preciso somar os valores das vendas que estão na tabela lc_controle a coluna total referente o mesmo período e depois dividir o valor de venda de cada item por esse total para poder calcular o percentual que o item tem sobre a venda total e depois definir se ele é A, b ou C

Como é possível fazer isso?

Answer (score -4):

```
select
d2.codprod,d2.vlr,d2.qtd,perc ,d2.pracu,
case when d2.pracu <= 80 then 'A'
when d2.pracu <= 95 then 'B'
ELSE 'C' END CLASSE



from (
select
d1.codprod,d1.vlr,d1.qtd,d1.totalgeral,d1.perc,sum(perc) over(order by d1.perc desc) pracu
from(
select
d.codprod,d.qtd,
d.vlr, sum(d.vlr) over() totalgeral, cast(d.vlr  as decimal(15,2)) / cast(sum(d.vlr) over() as decimal(15,3)) *100 perc

from(

select i.codprod,sum(precototalcomdesc) as vlr,sum(quantidade) as qtd from iten_vendatemp
 AS I INNER JOIN PRODUTOS AS P ON ( P.CODPROD = I.CODPROD) inner join vendas as
 v on ( v.codigovenda = i.codvenda)
 inner join formadepagamento as f on(f.id = v.idformpag) where  I.situacao = 2
 and f.NAOTOTALIZARRELATORIOVENDAS = false group by codprod order by  vlr desc) d)d1)d2
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).